# extracting character from character string as per certain conditions

Tags: r, regex, string

Let's say

```
x = "R is so tough for SAS programmer"
y = "R why you so hard"
```

Now we have to find the word before 8th place and the first space (" ") encountered going right to left, i.e. backwards.

In case of `x` it would be the word `"so"`

In the case of `y` it would be `"y"`

How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide us with a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @Martin, did you read the question? It includes an example with expected output

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have both strings in one vector:

```
x = c("R is so tough for SAS programmer", "R why you so hard")
```

Then, if I understand your question correctly, you can use a combination of `substr` to extract the first 7 characters of each string and then `sub` to extract the part after the last space:

```
sub(".*\\s", "", substr(x, 1, 7))
#[1] "so" "y"
```

---

It may be safer to use

```
sub(".*\\s", "", trimws(substr(x, 1, 7), "right"))
```

which will cut off any whitespace on the right side of the vector resulting from `substr`. This ensures that the `sub` call won't accidentally match a space at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option with `word` and `sub`

```
library(stringr) 
word(sub("^(.{1,7}).*", "\\1", x), -1)
#[1] "so" "y"
```

#### data

```
x <- c("R is so tough for SAS programmer", "R why you so hard")
```

Comment: nice +1, is that a new function in stringr?

Comment: @docendodiscimus  `word` is from `stringr`.  It has been around for some time

Comment: I see. (I'd prefer substr for the extraction of the 1-7 letters)

Comment: @docendodiscimus  You are right, `substr` would be fast